# Command Not Found error after compiling Github software (Eddypro) on Ubuntu-based Linux Mint 20

Tags: bash, compiler-warnings, linux-mint

I am attempting to compile the Eddypro engine, a free and open source program from https://github.com/LI-COR/eddypro-engine, on my Linux Mint 20 machine with Gfortran.

Following their instructions I have cloned the repo, and ran:

```
$ cd prj
$ make rp
$ make fcc
```

Both of the make commands exit with out error, though there are some warnings:

- CHARACTER expression will be truncated in assignment
- ‘fitstable.dim[0].ubound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
- Unused dummy argument ‘npar’ at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
- ‘unstable_corr_fact[0]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
- Warning: Impure function ‘adddates’ at (1) might not be evaluated [-Wfunction-elimination]
- Array reference at (1) out of bounds (367 > 366) in loop beginning at (2) [-Wdo-subscript]
- Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Arithmetic IF statement at (1)
  ../src/src_rp/fft4/rfftb.F:177:72: 177 |       IF (IDO-2) 107,105,102
- etc...

Assuming these warnings are not critical, I attempt to run the binary files following the instructions here: https://www.licor.com/env/support/EddyPro/topics/command-line.html but get an error:

```
~/eddypro-engine-master/bin/linux$ eddypro_rp -v
bash: eddypro_rp: command not found
```

The binary files do exist:

```
~/Programs/eddypro-engine-master/bin/linux$ ls
eddypro_fcc  eddypro_rp

file eddypro_rp 
eddypro_rp: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=1ff120f0d366645bd85df564fb54d401b0a1c55c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either it's not in your path (`.` is not automatically in the path) or it isn't executable (unlikely). Try `./eddypro_rp` for the former and `ls -l eddypro_rp` for the latter and check for `rwx` to appear on the left.

Comment: Wow. Super simple. Just needed to run

    ./eddypro_rp

Curious, why doesn't it find it if I am in the directory and type the file name?

Comment: I think it's a security issue. Suppose you're an admin, and you cd to a user's directory and type `ls`. If the user had a Trojan horse in their directory which they named `ls`, and it automatically looked in the current directory, it would launch the Trojan horse instead. Best to require `.` to have to explicitly be in the path.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!